# Uniform Convergence: Poisson Kernel

Tags: partial-differential-equations, uniform-convergence, polar-coordinates, harmonic-functions

If we fix $θ_∗ > 0$, then
$P(r, θ) → 0$ uniformly on the set $ \left\lbrace θ : |θ| ≥ θ_∗ \right\rbrace $ as $r → a^-$
$$P(r,\theta)  = \frac{a^2-r^2}{a^2-2r\cos(\theta)+r^2}$$ 
$0\leq r <a,\textrm{ } -\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$

(Hint: $a^2 − 2ar cos(θ) + r^2 = (a − r)^2 + 2ar(1 − \cos θ)$.)

So far I've gotten:

$ \lim_{r → a^-} \max_{|θ| ≥ θ_∗} \left |  \frac{a^2-r^2}{(a − r)^2 + 2ar(1 − \cos θ)} \right |$

$ \lim_{r → a^-} \left |  \frac{a^2-r^2}{(a − r)^2 + 2ar} \right |$

$ \lim_{r → a^-} \left |  \frac{a^2-r^2}{a^2 + r^2} \right |$

$\left |  \frac{a^2-a^2}{a^2 + r^2} \right | = 0$

Is this correct? This seems to simple too be right.

Answer (score 1):

It is too easy (and incorrect). Your estimate seems to show that the maximum is $1$, independent of $\theta_\ast$. However, that is not true.

---

Let $s=r/a$. As $\theta_\ast\to0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\max_{r\lt a}\max_{|\theta|\ge\theta_\ast}\left|\frac{a^2-r^2}{(a−r)^2+2ar(1−\cos(\theta))}\right|
&=\max_{r\lt a}\left|\frac{a^2-r^2}{(a−r)^2+2ar(1−\cos(\theta_\ast))}\right|\\
&=\max_{r\lt a}\left|\frac{a^2-r^2}{(a−r)^2+4ar\sin^2(\theta_\ast/2)}\right|\\
&=\max_{s\lt 1}\left|\frac{1-s^2}{(1−s)^2+4s\sin^2(\theta_\ast/2)}\right|\\
&\sim\frac1{2\sin(\theta_\ast/2)}
\end{align}
$$
when $s\sim1-2\sin(\theta_\ast/2)$.

For $2\sin(\theta_\ast/2)=\left(\color{#C00000}{\frac13},\color{#00A000}{\frac1{10}},\color{#0000F0}{\frac1{30}},\color{#C0A000}{\frac1{100}}\right)$
[image]

Comment: Thank you for explaining where my thinking went wrong, but how does knowing this help find the uniform convergence of $Pr(r,\theta)$? I don't see the connection